# Any idea why exposed sort filters won't show up when configured correctly in D9.3 (works on simpletest.me instance)?

Tags: views, blocks

D9.3.12

I have a block view with sort criteria configured, but no exposed sort criteria show up in the preview or on the site when placed - "Exposed form in block: No" and "Use Ajax: Yes". If I duplicate it to be a page or embed (exact same settings) the sort criteria show up this persisted across multiple views.

I uninstalled BEF in case that was interfering with things, but there was no change.

Views related contrib installed:

```
Better Exposed Filters 8.x-5.0 
Chaos Tool Suite (ctools) 8.x-3.7 
Views Aggregator Plus 2.0.1 
Views Bulk Operations (VBO) 4.1.2
Views Field View 8.x-1.0-beta3 
Views fieldsets 8.x-3.4 
Views Simple Math Field 3.0.0
```

Here's some config that should be pretty universal:

```yaml
uuid: 1ab41219-fdc3-4f44-89f6-e5c057633456
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - node.type.article
    - node.type.batch
    - node.type.page
    - node.type.pcas
  module:
    - node
    - user
id: exposed_sort_test
label: 'Exposed Sort Test'
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: node_field_data
base_field: nid
display:
  default:
    id: default
    display_title: Default
    display_plugin: default
    position: 0
    display_options:
      title: 'Exposed Sort Test'
      fields:
        title:
          id: title
          table: node_field_data
          field: title
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: title
          plugin_id: field
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            make_link: false
            absolute: false
            word_boundary: false
            ellipsis: false
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          settings:
            link_to_entity: true
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
      pager:
        type: some
        options:
          offset: 0
          items_per_page: 10
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access content'
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      empty: {  }
      sorts:
        created:
          id: created
          table: node_field_data
          field: created
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: created
          plugin_id: date
          order: DESC
          expose:
            label: 'Authored on'
            field_identifier: created
          exposed: true
          granularity: second
      arguments: {  }
      filters:
        status:
          id: status
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          value: '1'
          group: 1
          expose:
            operator: ''
            operator_limit_selection: false
            operator_list: {  }
        type:
          id: type
          table: node_field_data
          field: type
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: type
          plugin_id: bundle
          operator: in
          value:
            all: all
            article: article
            page: page
            batch: batch
            pcas: pcas
          group: 1
          exposed: false
          expose:
            operator_id: ''
            label: ''
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: ''
            operator_limit_selection: false
            operator_list: {  }
            identifier: ''
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
            reduce: false
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
      style:
        type: default
      row:
        type: fields
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          query_comment: ''
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_tags: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      use_ajax: true
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'url.query_args:sort_by'
        - 'url.query_args:sort_order'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
  block_1:
    id: block_1
    display_title: Block
    display_plugin: block
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'url.query_args:sort_by'
        - 'url.query_args:sort_order'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
  page_1:
    id: page_1
    display_title: Page
    display_plugin: page
    position: 2
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      path: sortme
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'url.query_args:sort_by'
        - 'url.query_args:sort_order'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
```

And views previews, showing the lack of exposed filters on the block:

[image: block view with no sort criteria exposed]

with them appearing on the page view:

[image: page view with sort criteria exposed]

and rendered on site (in case it was a preview issue):

[image: rendered block, no sort criteria]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Chaos Views Tools - I backed up my db, then killed all my views contrib - sorts were exposed! Went back one by one and ctools is when it stopped working. Restored again and tried to reasonably uninstall as much as I can without disabling ctools to see if it was a conflict between two modules and that seems pretty unlikely.

[image: contrib installed]

[image: no exposed sort]

update: this is repeatable on simplytest.me